# Как открыть проект Telegram в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telegram

Пытаемся прокачать стандартный клиент телеграма под Андроид.
Уже выполнил такие действия:

1. Скачал с Гита командой
   `git clone --recursive -j8 https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git`
2. Изменил название пакета.
3. Добавил свой JSON гугл сервисов.
4. В папке  `C:\Telegram\TMessagesProj` запустил файл `ndk-build.cmd` Компиляция ndk вроде прошла успешно.
   `C:\Telegram\TMessagesProj> C:/Users/Console/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd`
5. После этих действий приложение все равно вылетает с ошибкой

   > Android Telegram App -> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

На строках в файле ConnectionManager.java:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так сделал?

P.S.
По советам ниже проверил пути к библиотеке. В классе NativeLoader вывел путь библиотеки, которую он загружает. /data/app/org.telegramnf-1/lib/arm
По этому пути единственная подгружаемая библиотека есть, то есть вариант с неверным путем отпадает.
Вот скрин полной ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полность текст ошибки добавьте. Там должно быть указано, какой именно нативной библиотеки не хватает.

Comment: Ищите в тексте приложения где производится линковка c нативными либами: `System.loadLibrary()` - проблема где-то там. Скорее всего после переименования пакетов поменялось место где лежат либы `*.so` - по умолчанию должны лежать в каталоге `/jni`

Comment: @Barmaley проверил путь, библиотека там есть и от туда загружается. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление вопроса.

Comment: Можно выложить полную трассировку в тексте, а не в виде скриншота? Правый край скриншота обрезан - не все видно